# Move the Start Menu in Windows 7 Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, start-menu

Is there anyway to move the Start Menu button on the taskbar in Windows 7?  I've decided to try moving the taskbar to the left so I have more vertical screen real estate, but I would like the start menu to be at the bottom of the bar.  Is there anyway to move it?

Comment: no joy, however, while i was looking around i found a little gadget that is moving the start button or system tray around the taskbar, unfortunately, this only works with XP and only if the taskbar is at the top or the bottom. useless but funny :) http://keznews.com/6270_Move_Windows_XP_Start_Button___System_Tray_on_Taskbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for moving Start button. If you are docked to left, button will always be at top.

Comment: Well, since Windows 7 was really my idea, I need to send Microsoft an e-mail and they'll fix that right up.